# incomplete backButton function objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uinavigationbar, back-button

I'm currently trying to create a popover menu, with a navigationBar, and a backButton that bring me back to the main ViewController.

Posts over here helped me a lot to create my functions.
I put NSLogs in my code and everything works perfectly.... But the backButton itself, which do nothing.

So. My back button is declared in my .h file like that:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;
```

and I have those two functions in my .m :

```
-(void)setBackButton:(UIButton *)backButton
{
    NSLog(@"setBackButton: called");

    [_backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButtonItem];
}

- (IBAction)backBtn:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"backBtn: called");
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And when I click my backButton, the NSLog is correctly displayed.

But I have no idea of what to call to go back to my view. Does anyone have an idea ??

Comment: try popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES

Comment: I just tried and it changed nothing ^^ But in my whole code I can't see anything that would make properly start a back function x)

Comment: put a breakpoint in the method backBtn, and try to print the description of navigation controller, and try to print your root view controller.  BTW how do you present the new controller from your root view controller ?

Comment: Is `[self navigationController]` nil? What's its controllers: `[[self navigationController] viewControllers]`? If it's a popover, I'm guessing that you show it modally, then it has to dismiss, not pop, no?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Adèle. In the future please refrain from including offending code in your posts (be it only debug logs or comments). Thanks!

Comment: everything is nil yes. Actually I can't even find a "navigation controller" in my breakpoint prints.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis sorrry about that, I completly forgot that I had words like that in it. Won't happen again, thanks :)

Comment: If it's nil, then there is no navigation controller for your view controller. Did you add one either using storyboard/through code ?

Comment: Yes there is, the navigation controller is just before my main view (which is basically named viewController), and then my menu :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two controllers A and B
So if you are adding

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in controller B, it will only work only when you are pushed to B using proper navigation method from A.

In case of storyboard, you have to push from A to B is like

```
A *aCntrl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aCntrl animated:YES];
```

In case of non-storyboard, you have to push from A to B is like

```
A *aCntrl = [[A alloc] initWithNibName:@"A" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aCntrl animated:YES];
```

In this case

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

should work.

Just check how you are navigation from A to B. It should be pushViewController and not presentViewController.

Comment: Wait, so I just have to include my main viewcontroller in my menuviewcontroller.h, and then try the lines you put ? I'll try that right now. But it feel odd, as in my main viewController i have a prepareforsegue function and all of that stuff. It doesn't feel logic x)

Comment: Hm, the problem I have is an uncaught exception. It doesn't recognize my viewcontroller identifier (so A in your post :p). I just put ViewController (tried View Controller also). I'd like to change it in my storyBoard, but I can't find where, is it possible to do that with viewcontrollers ?? :o

Comment: Ahah, as I said, I didn't solved the issue at all ^^ I just successed to remane my viewController ID. But I'm roaming other answers since this morning. And I have the exact same code, it's really weird...   I think I maybe misunderstood difference between UIButton and UIBarButtonItem ?

Comment: Try this 

First write method as @selector(backBtn). Dont add : in that.

and 

btnBack mthod with 

- (void)backBtn {
    NSLog(@"backBtn: called");
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

This should work if I am visualizing your problem in correct way.

Comment: The NSLog appears everytime. I deleted the ":" after my selector (I have now a warning "undeclared selector") and changed the lines you put in your answer with a [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] and nothing changed. I think the problem may be completly somewhere else, like, something i forgot in my sotryboard? Or somewhere else, but something stupid for sure...